# Columns not containing text

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, paragraph

I'm using Zurb Foundation columns and trying to get my paragraph text contained within a column but it is displaying right across the screen, I'm not sure why this is happening, it can be fixed with padding and/or margins but that is causing problems on larger screen sizes.

The problem part is the whiskey section down the page. Any ideas what the problem is here ?

[PROBLEM PAGE](http://rowandesign.info/)

Thanks

CSS:

```
#newwhiskeylp p {
color: #f9f8fd; 
font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
font-size: 2.5rem;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 2.8rem;
text-align:center;
margin-left:auto;
margin:right:auto;
margin-top:-50px;
display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns" id="whiskeywide">
    <div class="small-12 medium-offset-6 medium-6 large-offset-2 large-10 
    columns" id="newwhiskeylp"><img class="whiskeytitlelp" src="<?php 
    bloginfo('template_url');  ?>/Images/GOOD-WHISKEY-TITLE-D.png">
        <p>The finest range of Irish whiskeys rich in flavour and aromas, 
        aged to blossom fully to deliver a well seasoned Irish take on 
        perfection.
        <a style="color:#FFEB7F;" href="http://rowandesign.info/whiskey- 
        menu-lp/">Read more</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should put your code here to see the problem.

Comment: Code added now thanks

Comment: You need to go and error-check your CSS, lots of mess-ups in there. https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frowandesign.info%2F&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: Thanks for the link. I cleaned up code as much as I could

Comment: Ok, haven't been able to check until now but the code clean up looks to have worked - thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
<div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
    <!-- <div class="small-offset-1 small-10 medium-offset-4 medium-6 large-offset-6" id="newwhiskeylp"> -->
    <div class="float-center  small-10  medium-6 large-6">

      <!-- grid-container will keep everything off the edges.
      the grid is 12 columns wide.
      small-offset-1 create a one column space then only 10 columns of text
      same logic with the medium and large offsets.  -->

        <p>The finest range of Irish whiskeys rich in flavour and aromas,
        aged to blossom fully to deliver a well seasoned Irish take on
        perfection.
        <a style="color:#FFEB7F;" href="http://rowandesign.info/whiskey-
        menu-lp/">Read more</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div></div>
```